# Oobleck (cornstarch & water) CLOG in DRAIN!

Tags: drain

Oobleck (cornstarch & water)was poured down my drain, maybe 4oz., by my child and is now stopped up.  Now what?  Can I unclog it or will it require a plumber?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't pour hot water down the sink. It'll cook the starch and turn it into a giant gravy lump, which will be even harder to clear out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's only 4oz, the quickest fix will be to fill the sink until you can get your toilet plunger submerged in it. Then plunge repeatedly. Once it starts draining rinse the starch down with plenty of water.

If that fails, take the [p-trap](https://www.google.com/search?q=p-trap&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgr_Pm2P7QAhWFh1QKHQSQDTYQsAQILg&biw=1162&bih=618) off and give it a good cleanout. Likely the starch settled down there.

Comment: I imagine running one of those cheap plastic  hair removal tools up and down the drain a few minutes would also help to break up the clumps. But if all else fails, there's always boric acid!